# UserProfileInfoForm object is not callable

Tags: python, django

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from practise.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

                profile.save()

                registered = True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request, 'registration.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'resigtered': registered})
```

**error**

> Internal Server Error: /index/register/ Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "C:\Users\Faris\PycharmProjects\djangoProject4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\Faris\PycharmProjects\djangoProject4\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 179, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Faris\PycharmProjects\djangoProject4\practise\views.py",
> line 22, in register
> profile = profile_form(commit=False) TypeError: 'UserProfileInfoForm' object is not callable [19/Aug/2020 21:05:57]
> "POST /index/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 68871

Comment: Please at least consider explaining about your issue when you add code.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
profile = profile_form(commit=False)
```

is the where the error occurs. `profile_form` is not a method(function), but you called it as if it were a function.

Change that line like so:

```
profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
```

This is perhaps what you wanted.